# How to setup PhoneGap without xCode installation?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am beginner to PhoneGap app development. Below are my queries.
1. Is it possible to setup PhoneGap SDK without  Xcode installation.
2. If YES then how to do same.
3. If NO then is there any way I can write a iphone application without Xcode installation(I dont want to pay 99$, because I m a begineer).
4. I have a MAC, Windows, Linux PCs. Tell me all the free SWs. Its ok if I am not able to test the application initially.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to setup PhoneGap SDK without Xcode installation.

No.

> If NO then is there any way I can write a iphone application without Xcode installation(I dont want to pay 99$, because I'm a beginner)

XCode is free. [It's in the AppStore](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12). The $99 is to give you the ability to distribute applications in the AppStore and run it on a device. You will still be able to develop and run applications in an emulator for free.

Answer (score 2):

I you don't want to install the dev environment, you can use their cloud service to build native apps written in HTML+CSS+Javascript. It's free and allows you to target all the supported platforms.

https://build.phonegap.com/

You only have to upload your finished app and get a compiled, native app.

Comment: what are the minimum requirements? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993277/phonegap-2-0-project-setup-without-native-sdk