# phonegap 2.0 project setup without native SDK

Tags: javascript, cordova, sdk, build

I'm attempting to build my first phonegap application using the phonegap build cloud compiler. In the instructions there it says to remove phonegap.js before uploading... Where is this mystery file? I downloaded the latest phonegap and nothing in the /Libs/ looks right. There seems to be no documentation on how to setup your root HTML page properly to be compiled with phonegap.

"Once you've included the necessary assets, remove the phonegap.js (cordova.js) as Build will automatically inject it during compile time." - https://build.phonegap.com/docs/preparing-your-app#what_do_i_upload

I'm under the impression that I just need to use the JS API for code completion and then let the cloud compiler do its work, but all the documentation revolves around installing an SDK for each platform. I don't want to use xCode or eclipse-- I just want to write javascript.

What is the bare minimum resources I need to include on my root HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the bare minimum resources I need to include on my root HTML
>   file?

You need just 2 files: **index.html** (may be the name "index.html" is configurable in the config.xml, I am not sure) and **config.xml**.

Here is a starter app: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start, take a look in the www folder.